# Problem with apples hiragana keyboard

Tags: discussion

So I use the Japanese Kana keyboard on an Apple iPhone, and i started off with a bunch of problems, but the solutions eventually showed themselves without much issue, such as how to use small characters or use characters like が. One issue that I haven’t been able to figure out is how to use the character を that’s pronounced just like お. It’s the character that you would see in between a food and 食べます. I started using the keyboard on Duolingo and whenever I needed to use the character it would be a Among the suggestions at the top of the keyboard, but outside of duo lingo I can’t get it to appear in the suggestions, and can only paste it from somewhere else like I did here. Does anyone know a way to type it?

Comment: Tap and hold わ and it will appear just like お does behind あ.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "Japanese kana keyboard" you mean the one that looks like the screenshot below:

[image: Japanese kana keyboard highlighting the を key, after dragging left from the わ key]

You'd wanna tap and hold わ, and then drag left to を, as shown on the screenshot. The screenshot shows わ, を, ん, and ー, since those are the options for that key, and ん is hiding the や key while the key is held. If your keyboard is set to "flick only," that's your only option.

If your keyboard is *not* set to "flick only," you should be able to get there by tapping on わ twice too.